# Is it dangerous to use eval in this way in Python to activate the functions of a script and if so what is an alternative?

Tags: python, design-patterns, databricks

So perhaps a bit of a weird design I have and would like some critique. So the team I am working with has all of their code in github and they are running in on some in-house server through the command line. My job is to take the existing code and transpose it into a Databricks environment. In order to make the updates to their github dynamic I shell into github and give it a github token and I am able to clone the entire repo onto the Databricks environment. Now that I have access the all the scripts and data that exists in their Repo I make global variables of each script. I put all of that code into a single file call auxiliary. Then I create another file called main and in that file I call the auxiliary file by running %run ./auxiliary, and this point I now have access to all the global variables there -- but I dont have access to the functions inside the global variables. So in order to activate/initialize them I run the exec() function which I understand compiles and evaluates anything you pass in. The scripts I pass in are just a bunch of functions. My question is does this design make sense and is it dangerous to use exec() this way?

Thanks

Comment: No, and yes.  I'm not familiar with databricks but if you're trying to build an API around a random Python module maybe FastAPI would be a better starting point?

Comment: @Samwise not an api, it is an ETL. I pull from data sources every few months and execute it his way.